# What is `pandas.DataFrame.apply` actually operating on?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, functional-programming

I have two questions, but first I will give the context. I am trying to use a pandas `DataFrame` with some existing code using a functional programming approach. I basically want to map a function to every row of a `DataFrame`, expanding the row using the double-asterisk keyword argument notation, where each column name of the `DataFrame` corresponds to one of the arguments of the existing function.

For example, say I have the following function.

```py
def line(m, x, b):
    y = (m * x) + b

    return y
```

And I have a pandas `DataFrame`

```py
data = [{"b": 1, "m": 1, "x": 2}, {"b": 2, "m": 2, "x": 3}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Returns
#    b  m  x
# 0  1  1  2
# 1  2  2  3
```

Ultimately, I want to construct a column in the `DataFrame` from the results of `line` applied to each row; something like the following.

```py
# Note that I'm using the list of dicts defined above, not the DataFrame.
results = [line(**datum) for datum in data]
```

I feel like I should be able to use some combination of `DataFrame.apply`, a `lambda`, probably `Series.to_dict`, and the double-asterisk keyword argument expansion but I can't figure out what is passed to the `lambda` in the following expression.

```py
df.apply(lambda x: x, axis=1)
#               ^
#               What is pandas passing to my identity lambda?
```

I've tried to inspect with `type` and `x.__class__`, but both of the following lines throw `TypeErrors`.

```py
df.apply(lambda x: type(x), axis=1)
df.apply(lambda x: x.__class__, axis=1)
```

I don't want to write/refactor a new `line` function that can wrangle some pandas object because I shouldn't have to. Ultimately, I want to end up with a `DataFrame` with columns for the input data and a column with the corresponding output of the `line` function.

My two questions are:

1. How can I pass a row of a pandas `DataFrame` to a function using keyword-argument expansion, either using the `DataFrame.apply` method or some other (functional) approach?
2. What exactly is `DataFrame.apply` passing to the function that I specify?

Maybe there is some other functional approach I could take that I'm just not aware of, but I figure pandas is a pretty popular library for this kind of thing and that's why I'm trying to use it. Also there are some data (de)serialization issues I'm facing that pandas should make pretty easy vs. writing a more bespoke solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)?

Comment: I did, but I don't see where they mention what's being operated on by `DataFrame.apply`. 100% possible I just missed it.

Comment: "Apply a function along an axis of the DataFrame. Objects passed to the function are Series objects whose index is either the DataFrame’s index (axis=0) or the DataFrame’s columns (axis=1)."

Comment: Thanks. I obviously haven't had enough coffee this morning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for.

**1)**

```
df.apply(lambda x: line(**x.to_dict()), axis=1)
```

**Result**

```
0    3
1    8
```

**2)**

The function for `df.apply(..., axis=1)` receives a `Series` representing a row with the column names as index entries.

Comment: Yeah, I was poking around at my code after I posted this and it turns out I was making it way more difficult than I needed to. In fact, I didn't even need `lambda x: line(**x.to_dict())` like you wrote above; `lambda x: line(**x)` works just fine.

Comment: Good to know - thanks.  Also, I feel like `df.apply(lambda x: type(x), axis=1)` should work.  I am investigating that.

Comment: A back door way to get the object type:  `df.apply(lambda x: x.fake)`